# Dependency of the properties of numbers' subsets

Tags: additive-combinatorics

Let $a$ be the number of different sums of all the subsets of a set $A$ of $n$ real numbers (let's suppose the sum of an empty set is $0$). Let $b$ be the number of ordered pairs of the subsets of $A$ with the same sums (the subsets in the pair may be the same one, but they are in that case only one pair). Prove that $6^n\ge ab$
 
I don't know if it will have any use but I figured out that the number of subsets is $2^n$, $2^n\ge a\ge 1$, $(2^n\cdot(2^n-1))\ge b\ge2^n$. $b$ for a subset of subsets with the same sum is increasing faster than the number of subsets inside this subset. Experimenting I only managed to receive sums of $2$s with different exponents.

Comment: Here is an approach for the new question.  We are partitioning the $2^n$ subsets into equivalence classes by their sums.  There are $a$ of these classes with numbers of subsets $c_1,c_2,\ldots c_a$.  We have $b=\sum_ic_i^2$.  If all the subsets are in the same equivalence class we have $a=1, b=4^n, ab=4^n \lt 6^n$.  If all the subsets are in their own equivalence class we have $a=2^n,b=2^n,ab=4^n \lt 6^n$.  We need to use the fact that you can't get the equivalence classes too large because a partition with one class of size.

Comment: If you have $2^{n-2}$ classes with one subset each and one class with $3\cdot 2^{n-2}$ you will violate the $6^n$.  I think you can show that no class will have very many members, so $b$ will not be too large.

Comment: @RossMillikan one class with 3*2^(n-2) subsets?

Comment: Yes, that causes $ab$ to be maximal.  I believe that is not achievable with the way of generating the classes from subset sums.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you prove it causes ab to be maximal? I still don't know how to go further

Comment: I used the fact that if there are $k$ singletons and $2^n-k$ in one equivalence class, $b=(2^n-k)^2+k$, took the derivative of $ab$ with respect to $k$, ignored the terms without $2^n$ as small, and set it to zero.

Comment: @RossMillikan do you know some kind of theorem that will restrain b in our case?

Comment: No.  I suspect that $b$ will be greatest when $A$ is a set of numbers in arithmetic progression so $a=\frac 12n(n+1)+1$ equivalence classes, but I have no proof of that.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, it is not true.  There are $2^n$ subsets of $A$.  We can arrange that all subsets have different sums, for example by taking the elements of $A$ to be distinct powers of $2$.  Then $a=2^n=b$ and $ab=2^{2n}=4^n \lt 6^n$.  I think you want the inequality in the other direction.

Comment: Yes. My mistake. You're right.

Comment: Could you try now?